# Image vertically aligned in div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center this image vertically inside a div. As you can see I've accomplished that, however, it's still pushed slightly towards the bottom of the div. I can't find any reasons why this would be and I've even tried a different image.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="site-header">
            <img class="logo" src="CGLOGO.png" alt="logo">
</div>
```

**My CSS:**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #F7B267;
}
.site-header {
    background: #eee;
    color: #555;
    height: 3.125em;
    line-height: 3.125em;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.logo {
    max-height: 75%;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
```

**Result:**

[image: Output]

Comment: the orange line underneath indicates a margin-bottom, try removing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can center it with flexbox:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #F7B267;
}
.site-header {
    background: #eee;
    color: #555;
    height: 3.125em;
    line-height: 3.125em;
    display: flex;
}
.logo {
    display: block;
    max-height: 75%;
    margin: auto 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways to vertically center on a div one of it is

```
<div class="site-header">
   <img class="logo" src="CGLOGO.png" alt="logo">
</div>

<style>
.site-header {
   position:relative;
   height:400px;
   width:100%;
}
.site-header img {
   position:absolute;
   top:50%;
   height: 100px;
   transform:translateY(-50%);
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your `.site-header` class with the following

```
.site-header {
    background: #eee;
    color: #555;
    height: 3.125em;
    line-height: 3.125em;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; /* For vertical alignment*/
    // justify-content: center; /* For horizontal alignment*/
}
```